# Scipy filter returning nan Values only

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, signal-processing

I'm trying to filter an array that contains nan values in python using a scipy filter:

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal as sp

def apply_filter(x,fs,fc):
    l_filt = 2001
    b = sp.firwin(l_filt, fc, window='blackmanharris', pass_zero='lowpass', fs=fs)

    # zero-phase filter:
    xmean = np.nanmean(x)
    y = sp.filtfilt(b, 1, x - xmean, padlen=9)
    y += xmean
    return y

my_array = [13.049393453879606, 11.710994125276567, 15.39159227893492, 14.053192950331884, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 18.57029068436713, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 15.893492027161058, 16.228091859311817, 15.558892195010298, np.nan, 8.866895551995118, 14.053192950331882]

tt = apply_filter(my_array,64,30)
```

In the code above, the value of "tt" is an array containing only nan values instead of the filtered my_array. What am I doing wrong? (ps. the array is just an example to make the code reproducible).

Answer (score 0):

Your input array `my_array` contains NaN values.

when you make input array without nans, output array has no nans too:

```
my_array = np.random.random(1000)  # input without NaNs
tt = apply_filter(my_array,64,30)  # output has no NaNs
```

It reminded me of good old [GIGO rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out)

Comment: I cannot get rid of the nans value for time-series analysis purposes: I need to apply the filter ignoring the nan values but preserving them in the output array.

Comment: then you will need to replace NaNs with zeros/some interpolation/whatever suits your purpose